# RxJava- loop through async tasks and wait for complete

Tags: groovy, rx-java

I'm attempting to do some async work on `n` items, and wait for all items to complete before proceeding.

What do I put in the `whatfunc?` location to have subscribe's onComplete fire once?

```
Observable.range(0, n)
    .<whatfunc?>({ s ->  doAsyncWorkThatReturnsObservable(s) })
    .(other?)
    .subscribe({println "All complete"})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flatMap](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#flatmap)

Be sure to provide closures to the correct arguments in subscribe. Example from link adjusted to fit your provided example:

```
Observable.range(0, n)
    .flatMap({n -> doAsyncWorkThatReturnsObservable(n)})
    .subscribe(
       { println(it); },                          // onNext
       { println("Error: " + it.getMessage()); }, // onError
       { println("Sequence complete"); }          // onCompleted
    );
```